# Sortable with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

So I use jQuery UI sortable plugin to sort photos in a small gallery.

```
$(function() {
  $("#area").sortable({
    items: '.sort-wrapper',
    cursor: "move",
    handle: ".photo-handler",
    opacity: 0.5,
    scroll: true,
    scrollSensitivity: 100,
    scrollSpeed: 5,
    revert: 100,
    tolerance: "pointer",
    update : function () {
      var order = $('#area').sortable('serialize');
      $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url : '/file.php',
      data : order
    });
  }
}).disableSelection();
```

On the same page I dynamically add and remove photos. PHP script returns HTML code with `div`'s with image links and buttons "remove" and "move" (sortable handler).

Example:

```
<div class="sort-wrapper">
  <a href="photo001.jpg"><img src="photo001m.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <button type="button" class="remove-this-photo">Remove</button>
  <button type="button" class="photo-handler">Move</button>
</div>
```

The problem is sortable stops working when I add new files or remove a file(s) from `#area`. I've been looking for solution, have found `sortable('refresh')` method, but it's not working for me.

The script which adds new photos in the `#area` is quite standard. I use `$.ajax({})` and `.done`, `.fail`, `.always` methods. 
I managed to use `sortable('destroy')` method when starting uploading new files and do something like this after uploading is finished:

```
.always(function() {
  $("#area").sortable();
});
```

The code above makes the `#area` sortable again, but I must copy all the settings again to configure it my way.
How to bind sortable to make it work after dynamic content is loaded or how to store all the settings outside `sortable()` and be able to use it again on the same page?

Answer (score 1):

If you add new content to the sortable element you'll need to refresh the initialised instance. To do that, call the [`refresh` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh), like this:

```
.always(function() {
  $("#area").sortable('refresh');
});
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. No errors, no warnings in console. Nothing. I think the problem might be because I don't use any function to add/append content to the `#area`. The dynamic content comes from PHP script which adds/remove file and then `echo` all photos (HTML structure) added to the album user is editing. I've seen examples with `sortable('refresh')` and all of them based on adding content using append or similar function in JS/jQuery.